# Find if an array exists in dict and is not empty

Tags: python

I want to check if an element exists in my JSON input and it looks that the code snippet below works

```
import json
y = {
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "test"
        }
    ]
}

p2 = json.dumps(y)

if 'attributes' not in p2:
    print("not found")
else:
    print("found")
```

I would now want to check if the attributes element is of type list and the list size

What is the pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: `type(y['attributes']) == list` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json_data = json.dumps({
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "test"
        }
    ]
})


item_dict = json.loads(json_data)
print(type((item_dict['attributes'])))    # list
print(len((item_dict['attributes'][0])))     # 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The result of `json.dumps` is a JSON-formatted string, so if you were to search `p2` you would have to do some kind of string matching. I.e. `'attributes:[' in p2` would match is *somewhere* in your JSON there is an "attributes" key name followed by an array. This solution isn't ideal though as it doesn't handle the case when your JSON string is formatted differently (e.g. with an indent).

The pythonic way is to check `y` itself, like the other answers suggest. Namely

```
('attributes' in y)  # True because it exists
(isinstance(y['attributes'], list))  # True because it's a list
```

The most pythonic way would be simply to *assume* it's a list and handle a failure if you hit one.

I also wanted to add a quick shoutout to the [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/) serialization library. It is intended to handle more sophisticated schema validation tasks, but you could apply it here as well to validate that the attributes field exists and it maps to a list. I.e.

```
y = { ... }  # like before...

from mashmallow import Schema, fields
class AttributesList(Schema):
    attributes = fields.List(fields.Dict())

al = AttributesList()
al.dumps(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `isinstance()` to check the type, it will return boolean

```
y = {
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "test"
        }
    ]
}

# p2 = json.dumps(y)

if 'attributes' not in y:
    print("not found")

else:
    print(y['attributes'])
    print(isinstance(y['attributes'], list))
    if isinstance(y['attributes'], list):
        print('its a list')
        print(len(y['attributes']))
    print("found")
```

**output:**

```
[{'name': 'test'}]
True
its a list
1
found
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet `p2` is a string (`json.dumps` converts `y` to a valid JSON object in a string)

`isinstance` is the preferred way to check so you would use:

```
if isinstance(y['attributes'], list):
    len(y['attributes'])
```